# Insert Quote using Data Loader

Tags: data-loader

I am trying to upload Quote in my Salesforce Org(Enterprise Edition).I am System Admin of my org.But when i am using Data Loader,there is no option of Quote for Insertion.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if modify all permission is given to quote object for you admin profile.
There is a check box to say show all objects check it & try if it give the quote object to allow import.